# Instead of returning Sum it returns NaN. Why is it so?

Tags: javascript

In the following code i am trying to return the sum of all arguments i pass to a function addNumbers. i try to print value of r on console. When i try to find out type of r, it returns number, but when i try to print value of r it returns NaN. Why is it so?

```
function addNumbers() {
    var r=0;
    console.log(arguments.length);
    for(var i=1;i<=arguments.length;i++){
        console.log(arguments[i]);
        r=r+arguments[i];
    } 
    r.toString;
    console.log(typeof r);//returns Number
    console.log(r);//returns NaN
}
var sum1 = addNumbers(1,4,3);  
sum1();
```

Comment: `r.toString;` doesn't do anything here.

Comment: and sum1() is not a function!

Comment: The `console.log(arguments[i]);` should already give you some unexpected results, no?

Comment: Don't fix code in your question, removing the actual problem, invalidating existing answers.

Comment: And where does `addNumbers` actually *return* anything?

Comment: @deceze I am Very Sorry . this is my first interaction to stackoverflow. Thanks for your guide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Arrays and array-like things in JavaScript start with index 0, so start with 0 and go to `<` length, rather than starting with 1 and going to `<=` length. You're going past the end of `arguments`, thus getting `undefined`, and `number+undefined` is `NaN`.

```
for(var i=0;i<arguments.length;i++)
//        ^   ^
```

A couple of other notes:

- `r.toString;` on its own does nothing
- `addNumbers` doesn't return anything, so it doesn't make sense to do `var sum1 = addNumbers(1,4,3)`; `sum1` will always be `undefined`
- Since `sum1` is `undefined`, not a function, it doesn't make sense to try to *call* it via `sum1()`

Comment: And in javascript the`typeof NaN` is number, which can be very confusing.

Comment: @OriDrori: `NaN` *is* of the number type. That's not a JavaScript thing. That's an IEEE-754 floating point specification thing.

Comment: Good to know that it's confusing in other programming languages as well :)

Comment: Thank You. @T.J. Crowder

Answer (score 1):

For loop condition should be `i < arguments.length` although index start from `0`.

While `i` reaches `arguments.length` value  `r` would be a number and `arguments[i]` would be`undefined`. The addition of a `Number` and `undefined` results `NaN`.

`sum1` would be `undefined` since the function returns nothing so remove the line `sum1();` otherwise, it will throw an error.

```js
function addNumbers() {
  var r = 0;
  console.log(arguments.length);
  for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
  //---------^^^---^^^^-----------
    console.log(arguments[i]);
    r = r + arguments[i];
  }
  r.toString;
  console.log(typeof r); //returns Number
  console.log(r); //returns NaN
}
addNumbers(1, 4, 3);
```

Comment: @T.J.Crowder : `sum1` would be undefined

Answer (score 0):

if you want sum1 to be defined as the output of the function all you have to do is return r in the function and set

sum1 = addNumbers(1,4,3);

like so:

```js
function addNumbers() {
  var r = 0;
  console.log(arguments.length);
  for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
    console.log(arguments[i]);
    r = r + arguments[i];
  }
  r.toString;
  console.log(typeof r); //prints our Number to console
  console.log(r); //prints out r to console
  return r;
}
var sum1 = addNumbers(1, 4, 3);
```

Answer (score 0):

All of the answers above are right but the main problem that causes to print `NaN` is having the condition `i<=arguments.length` in your 'for' loop. Because you have an 'index out of bound exception' there when i = arguments.length, which means when the arguments array size is 5 and i is finally 5 (at last iteration) it tries to access the index 5 as arguments[5] but arguments array's max index is 4. This element 'arguments[5]' is not a number (it is an undefined value) so you got 'NaN' when you try to add it to a number and print.

Here is a sample that explains the 'NaN' behaviour:

```js
var r = 1;
console.log("Value of r = " + r);
console.log("Type of r = " + typeof r);
var arr = [1];
console.log("Array arr = [1]");
console.log("Type of arr[0] = " + typeof arr[0]);
console.log("Value of arr[0] = " + arr[0]);
console.log("Exceed the index:");
console.log("Type of arr[1] = " + typeof arr[1]);
console.log("Add index '0' to r:");
r += arr[0];
console.log("Value of r = " + r);
console.log("Add index '1' to r:");
r += arr[1];
console.log("Value of r = " + r);
console.log("Type of r = " + typeof r);
```

If you update your code with `i<=arguments.length` you will see that your problem will be gone away.

Here is your fixed code:

```js
function addNumbers() {
    var r=0;
    console.log(arguments.length);
    for(var i=0;i<arguments.length;i++){
        console.log(arguments[i]);
        r=r+arguments[i];
    } 
    r.toString;
    console.log(typeof r);//returns Number
    console.log(r);//returns NaN
}
var sum1 = addNumbers(1,4,3);  
sum1;
```

*Note: sum1 is not a function, it is a variable so please update sum1(); to sum1; too. Also fixed 'i' start index from 1 to zero.*

You can check out the code by this [jsFiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/bu5m8Lmx/) (open your developer tools to see the result).